# Error in Bayesian hyperparameter optimization technique

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm using python jupyter notebook  to use Bayesian optimization technique for hyperparameter tuning for my RandomForest regression model. Here is my code after importing necessary libraries,

```
space = {'criterion': hp.choice('criterion', ['squared_error', 'absolute_error', 'friedman_mse', 'poisson']),
        'max_depth': hp.quniform('max_depth', 15,17,19,21,23),
        'max_features': hp.choice('max_features', ['sqrt', 'log2', None]),
        'min_samples_leaf': hp.quniform('min_samples_leaf', 2,3,4),
        'min_samples_split': hp.quniform('min_samples_split', 4,5,6),
        'n_estimator': hp.choice('n_estimators', [50,52,54,56,58])      
        }


def objective(space):
    model = RandomForestRegressor(criterion = space['criterion'],
                                 max_depth = space['max_depth',],
                                 max_features = space['max_features'],
                                 min_samples_leaf = space['min_samples_leaf'],
                                 min_samples_split = space['min_samples_split'],
                                 n_estimators = space['n_estimators']
                                 )
    r2 = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv = 5).mean()
    return {'r2 score': -r2, 'status': STATUS_OK}


trials = Trials()
best = fmin(fn = objective,
           space = space,
            algo = tpe.suggest,
            max_evals = 80,
            trials = trials
           )
best
```

But after running  the last block of code, I got this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[141], line 2
      1 trials = Trials()
----> 2 best = fmin(fn = objective,
      3            space = space,
      4             algo = tpe.suggest,
      5             max_evals = 80,
      6             trials = trials
      7            )
      8 best

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py:540, in fmin(fn, space, algo, max_evals, timeout, loss_threshold, trials, rstate, allow_trials_fmin, pass_expr_memo_ctrl, catch_eval_exceptions, verbose, return_argmin, points_to_evaluate, max_queue_len, show_progressbar, early_stop_fn, trials_save_file)
    537     fn = __objective_fmin_wrapper(fn)
    539 if allow_trials_fmin and hasattr(trials, "fmin"):
--> 540     return trials.fmin(
    541         fn,
    542         space,
    543         algo=algo,
    544         max_evals=max_evals,
    545         timeout=timeout,
    546         loss_threshold=loss_threshold,
    547         max_queue_len=max_queue_len,
    548         rstate=rstate,
    549         pass_expr_memo_ctrl=pass_expr_memo_ctrl,
    550         verbose=verbose,
    551         catch_eval_exceptions=catch_eval_exceptions,
    552         return_argmin=return_argmin,
    553         show_progressbar=show_progressbar,
    554         early_stop_fn=early_stop_fn,
    555         trials_save_file=trials_save_file,
    556     )
    558 if trials is None:
    559     if os.path.exists(trials_save_file):

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\hyperopt\base.py:671, in Trials.fmin(self, fn, space, algo, max_evals, timeout, loss_threshold, max_queue_len, rstate, verbose, pass_expr_memo_ctrl, catch_eval_exceptions, return_argmin, show_progressbar, early_stop_fn, trials_save_file)
    666 # -- Stop-gap implementation!
    667 #    fmin should have been a Trials method in the first place
    668 #    but for now it's still sitting in another file.
    669 from .fmin import fmin
--> 671 return fmin(
    672     fn,
    673     space,
    674     algo=algo,
    675     max_evals=max_evals,
    676     timeout=timeout,
    677     loss_threshold=loss_threshold,
    678     trials=self,
    679     rstate=rstate,
    680     verbose=verbose,
    681     max_queue_len=max_queue_len,
    682     allow_trials_fmin=False,  # -- prevent recursion
    683     pass_expr_memo_ctrl=pass_expr_memo_ctrl,
    684     catch_eval_exceptions=catch_eval_exceptions,
    685     return_argmin=return_argmin,
    686     show_progressbar=show_progressbar,
    687     early_stop_fn=early_stop_fn,
    688     trials_save_file=trials_save_file,
    689 )

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py:586, in fmin(fn, space, algo, max_evals, timeout, loss_threshold, trials, rstate, allow_trials_fmin, pass_expr_memo_ctrl, catch_eval_exceptions, verbose, return_argmin, points_to_evaluate, max_queue_len, show_progressbar, early_stop_fn, trials_save_file)
    583 rval.catch_eval_exceptions = catch_eval_exceptions
    585 # next line is where the fmin is actually executed
--> 586 rval.exhaust()
    588 if return_argmin:
    589     if len(trials.trials) == 0:

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py:364, in FMinIter.exhaust(self)
    362 def exhaust(self):
    363     n_done = len(self.trials)
--> 364     self.run(self.max_evals - n_done, block_until_done=self.asynchronous)
    365     self.trials.refresh()
    366     return self

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py:278, in FMinIter.run(self, N, block_until_done)
    273 self.trials.refresh()
    274 # Based on existing trials and the domain, use `algo` to probe in
    275 # new hp points. Save the results of those inspections into
    276 # `new_trials`. This is the core of `run`, all the rest is just
    277 # processes orchestration
--> 278 new_trials = algo(
    279     new_ids, self.domain, trials, self.rstate.integers(2 ** 31 - 1)
    280 )
    281 assert len(new_ids) >= len(new_trials)
    283 if len(new_trials):

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\hyperopt\tpe.py:859, in suggest(new_ids, domain, trials, seed, prior_weight, n_startup_jobs, n_EI_candidates, gamma, verbose)
    857 t0 = time.time()
    858 # use build_posterior_wrapper to create the pyll nodes
--> 859 observed, observed_loss, posterior = build_posterior_wrapper(
    860     domain, prior_weight, gamma
    861 )
    862 tt = time.time() - t0
    863 if verbose:

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\hyperopt\tpe.py:813, in build_posterior_wrapper(domain, prior_weight, gamma)
    810 observed = {"idxs": pyll.Literal(), "vals": pyll.Literal()}
    811 observed_loss = {"idxs": pyll.Literal(), "vals": pyll.Literal()}
--> 813 posterior = build_posterior(
    814     # -- vectorized clone of bandit template
    815     domain.vh.v_expr,
    816     # -- this dict and next represent prior dists
    817     domain.vh.idxs_by_label(),
    818     domain.vh.vals_by_label(),
    819     observed["idxs"],
    820     observed["vals"],
    821     observed_loss["idxs"],
    822     observed_loss["vals"],
    823     pyll.Literal(gamma),
    824     pyll.Literal(float(prior_weight)),
    825 )
    827 return observed, observed_loss, posterior

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\hyperopt\tpe.py:705, in build_posterior(specs, prior_idxs, prior_vals, obs_idxs, obs_vals, obs_loss_idxs, obs_loss_vals, oloss_gamma, prior_weight)
    703 b_args = [obs_below, prior_weight] + aa
    704 named_args = {kw: memo[arg] for (kw, arg) in node.named_args}
--> 705 b_post = fn(*b_args, **named_args)
    706 a_args = [obs_above, prior_weight] + aa
    707 a_post = fn(*a_args, **named_args)

TypeError: ap_quniform_sampler() got multiple values for argument 'size'
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: You are misusing the `quniform` distribution; it takes three parameters, but you're passing more.